# I can see my Team Calendar

Tags: asana, asana-api, asana-connect

I can see my Team Calendar on ASANA. In one of my projects I see and in the other I can't. What could have happened? 
I researched in the FAQ, but i can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check if you have permission to work in the project where you couldn't see the calendar. If not, you need the permission from the administrator. Or you could try going to my task, see your calendar from there; and it will show up all your tasks in all projects. I hope it helps.

Comment: In this project I have administrator permission, but I still can not. I have two projects that are identical in terms of permission and one I can see and the other can not.

Comment: @RafaelAmandio Try this: Go to My tasks -> click on calendar. If you still cannot see the tasks, you might not be assigned or followed in the project.